# When querying a dataframe using spark/scala locally, how to change output of values in a column?

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Im using **spark/scala locally** to transform **json** files into a **dataframe**.

My current dataframe has a column with 'Male' and 'Female' values, shown below. I want to change where you see **'Male'** in the dataframe to **'M'** and likewise for **'Female'** to **'F'** using spark **-sql**.

So far I have:

```
val results = spark.sql("SELECT name, case WHEN gender = 'Male' then 'M' WHEN gender = 'Female' then 'F' else 'Unknown' END from ocupation_table)
```

but it's creating a separate column and I want it to **rename** the values in the **existing 'gender'** column.

[Tab to view dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfr9t.png)

Comment: Use an alias to rename the column expression to 'Gender' and select it

Comment: `END as gender from occupation_table`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark's [`withColumn(...)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method to achieve this. It will replace a named column if it already exists. Something like this should do the trick:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val results = df.withColumn("gender", substring(df("gender"), 0, 1))
```